# Gradient drawable getColor() method for API 16 or less

Tags: android, colors, imageview, gradientdrawable

So I need to change the color an ImageView programmatically, and getBackGround returns a GradientDrawable which has a setColor method but no getColor, at least not for API 16 or lower. So my question is: is there like a support library version of the GradiantDrawable ?. If there is, how can I use it considering that I'm using an xml drawable that has a layer-list as the root and I only want to change one of the layer's color and then be able to retrieve the color later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `ColorDrawable` for that layer instead. If necessary, you can set the drawable for a given layer at runtime using [`layerDrawable.setDrawableByLayerId()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html#setDrawableByLayerId(int,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)), but you should only have to do that at most once.